# Steps to add model level permission in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have my legacy database.I created models using inspectdb.I am able to see my tables in admin page . I created 4 users and i want to implement role-based permission for each model. I just show you with example what i did in model to add permissions like edit, view, delete.
Example:-

```
class BusinessIntegrationSourceCategory(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    source_category = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'business_integration_source_category'
        permissions = (
            ("view_category", "view category"),
             ("add_category", "Add category"),
            ("delete_category", "Delete category"),
        )
```

Now where i can add the next steps to add role based permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This from The Django docs.

> **[Handling object permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-object-permissions)**
>
> Django’s permission framework has a foundation for object permissions,
>   though there is no implementation for it in the core. That means that
>   checking for object permissions will always return False or an empty
>   list (depending on the check performed). An authentication backend
>   will receive the keyword parameters obj and user_obj for each object
>   related authorization method and can return the object level
>   permission as appropriate.

So as said: **An authentication backend will receive the keyword parameters *`obj`* and *`user_obj`***.

And these tow variables are the seeds of object level permissions, but the default backend `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` does not take advantage of that. So you should create a custom backend.

> **Note:**
>
> **If you use custom `User` model, [your user model should subclass `PermissionsMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions), because The has_perm method of `PermissionsMixin` passes the work off to the registered authentication backends.**

**Try:**

`backends.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class MyAuthenticationBackend:

    def authenticate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
        if perm == "view_category":
            return True # everybody can view
        # otherwise only the owner or the superuser can delete
        return user_obj.is_active and obj.user.pk==user_obj.pk

    def has_perms(self, user_obj, perm_list, obj=None):
        return all(self.has_perm(user_obj, perm, obj) for perm in perm_list)
```

In `settings.py` file add:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'your_app.backends.MyAuthenticationBackend',
    # Your other auth backends, if you were using the default,
    # then comment out the next line, otherwise specify yours
    # 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
    ]
```

**Note: every model already has [default permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) (add, change and delete)**

I hope this will push you forward.

Comment: Thanks for your response Yusef .But I used my existing database tables to show on the Admin page.i created new user from admin page i want to give delete and change access on few tables but i can't see the tables name in side  available User permissions tab in side user screen. As we know every model already has default permissions (add, change and delete) so how can i see my tables names in user section