# assign multiple user to multiple events Django

Tags: python, html, django

So I'm trying to write a method which should enable the admin user who add users to assign them into events so that it becomes:users can have many events & events can have many users, and I want that to happen inside the event details, I couldn't figure it out

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    # events = models.ManyToManyField(Event)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    phone_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,blank=True, null=True)
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length = 120 , default='',blank=True, null=True)
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length = 120, default='',blank=True, null=True)
    non_listed_entity = models.CharField(max_length = 120, default='', blank=True)
    first_time = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username



class TraineeInEvent(models.Model):
    trainees = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, null=True, related_name="TraineeInOneEvent")

    def __str__(self):
        return '-'.join([str(trainee) for trainee in self.trainees.all()])
```

**views.py**

```
def event_detail(request, event_id):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
        form = TraineeInEvent()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = TraineeInEvent(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        context = {
            "event": event,
            "form":form,
        }
    else:
        return redirect('cal:no-access')

    return render(request, 'cal/detail.html', context)
```

any Idea?

Comment: Do you want to add some users who can add the event to any trainee user? Also that user (who adds) gets permission by admin? right?

Comment: @AsaduzzamanSohel No there is only one user admin who will first register many users and then assign those users(trainees) to different events , one trainee could be assigned to many events, and it's happening in a web page not from admin page, do you have an idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained where you want to do this: Inside the admin or on some web page.

As far as I can see in your view you are assigning a model to a form here

```
form = TraineeInEvent()
```

(TraineeInEvent is a model you declared in models). A ModelForm with TraineeInEvent as model should do what you expect.

```
class TraineeInEventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = TraineeInEvent
        fields = ('trainees', )
```

Edit: More details

What I would suggest is to add the trainees field to your Event model

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # Other fields
    trainees = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, null=True, related_name="TraineeInOneEvent")
```

The form

```
class TraineeInEventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('trainees', ) # add any fields needed
```

The view

```
def event_detail(request, event_id):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
        form = TraineeInEventForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = TraineeInEventForm(request.POST, instance=event)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('to_whatever_url') # You should redirect after successful save

    else:
        return redirect('cal:no-access')

    return render(request, 'cal/detail.html', context)
```

Comment: I realised that your TraineeInEvent does not have any reference to the event. Updated the answer to a full example

Answer (score 0):

You have to user Permission. It can be `model level` permission or `object level` permission. The only user add-in trainee who has permission to create this action.
You can follow this link: [Steps to add model level permission in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244055/steps-to-add-model-level-permission-in-django) and
[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)